# Настройка хоста для доступа извне локальной сети

Tags: c#, wcf

Как настроить хост, чтобы клиенты могли "достучаться" из-за пределов локальной сети?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить конечную точку в хосте (или же это нужно делать в конфиге клиента), чтобы получить доступ к службе, не используя локальную сеть?

Answer (score 2):

Если я все правильно понял, то этот вопрос скорее адресуется к тому, как настроить ТСР-порт на локальном компьютере и разрешить входящие соединения. В общих чертах: нужно обратиться к провайдеру с просьбой открыть порт, либо настроить модем. В случае из моей практики для решения похожей задачи нужно было воспользоваться port-forwarding в настройках adsl модема. Кроме того, нужно иметь ввиду статический ли внешний IP у хоста или нет. Если нет - можно попробывать воспользоваться сервисами Dynamic DNS.